# What is wrong with this configuration of sudoers file?

Tags: shell, sudo, sudoers

I have to execute a shell script as another user, but without be prompted for password.

I've edited the etc/sudoers file with visudo, adding the following line.

```
_www  localhost=(otheruser) NOPASSWD:/patho/to/my/script.sh
```

If I understand how sudo works, this means that user _www is allowed to execute like user 'otheruser', without be prompted for password, only from localhost.

is that correct?

the system continue to prompt for the password...

Comment: No, it means that the _www user can do `/patho/to/my/script.sh`, which is not enough. You should add `/bin/sh` to make it an executable command. All together, `/bin/sh /patho/to/my/script.sh`.

Comment: Thank you, but it still prompt me for the password

Comment: This question is off-topic here. If the question was about the script file itself, it would be appropriate, but you're asking about system configuration instead. Your question would be more suitable for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: Ok, I will ask to the right place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks right to me.
Sudoer rules at the bottom override rules above. Do you possibly have another below it? Sudoers rules are interpreted in order. A rule at the bottom will override a conflicting rule above it. Make sure you don't have an other policy overriding it below.